# HTTPD Redirect Rule as Proxy is giving me file not found error. How do I proxy to an external url?

Tags: apache-httpd, aws, elasticsearch, rewrite

I have a reverse proxy to AWS Elasticsearch. I am having issues with using `RedirectRule`: no matter what I try, my URL is being interpreted as a file.

```
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /test-api https://vpc-cls-elasticsearch-test-tmqu2s2mcftvsuqe.amazonaws.com [P]

ProxyPassReverse /test-api https://vpc-cls-elasticsearch-test-tmqu2s2mcftvsuqe.amazonaws.com
```

Calling https://example.com/test-api always returns this error:

```
The requested URL /cls-api was not found on this server
```

How can I get this to work without the existence of an actual file on my server?

Comment: I'd really recommend you remove `ProxyRequests On` unless you [understand why](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) you want it

Comment: Is this definition in a virtual host section? Are you sure you're referencing the correct (virtual) host when testing this proxy configuration? Have you enabled logging? If not, why not? What do the log files tell you about the request?

Comment: Try replacing the `RewriteRule` with the [recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html) `ProxyPass` directive, `ProxyPass /test-api https://vpc-cls-elasticsearch-test-tmqu2s2mcftvsuqe.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick response.  roaima I have turned off ProxyRequests.

Comment: I managed to resolve this by setting 
SSLEngine on
ProxyAddHeaders off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this question with the following inside
`<VirtualHost _default_:443>`

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLEngine on
ProxyAddHeaders off
ProxyPreserveHost off
 
RewriteRule  /test-api  https://vpc-x-x-x-01-tmqu2s2mcftvsyg3mweduvu.example.amazonaws.com:443 [P]
ProxyPassReverse  /test-api  https://vpc-cls-elasticsearch-01-tmqu2s2mcftvsuqeyg3mweduvu.us-gov-west-1.es.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: You'd still be better off with ProxyPass instead of RewriteRule

Comment: You can't because of a 96 character limit in httpd

Comment: It was fixed in 2.4.7

Comment: Sorry I have to use 2.4.6.

Comment: If you're going to use obsolete, insecure, and unsupported software you should note it in the question. Why would you want to use anything less than the current 2.4.46?

Comment: I am on 2.4.6 not 2.4.46.  RHEL 7 has support only up to 2.4.6. As far as it being insecure, we backport bug fixes so technically our version is not insecure.